# How to add and remove Heroku Dynos through platform API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, heroku, dyno

I want to add and remove Heroku Dynos through platform API
Just like we do

```
ps:scale web=0
```

in Heroku toolbelt CLI.

I have already tried

```
POST /apps/{app_id_or_name}/dynos/{dyno_id_or_name}/actions/stop
```

but it doesn't do anything however the response has a status code of 200.

Comment: Running ps:stop on dynos that are part of a scaled process will automatically be restarted.

Comment: @svikramjeet I know about the command, but I need to do it through the Heroku platform API

Comment: You can't remove dynos with API , please refer to docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the dyno stop `ps:stop` behavior outlined in this question:

Running `ps:stop` on dynos that are part of a scaled process will automatically be restarted. In Private Spaces, `ps:stop` will terminate and replace the dedicated instance running the dyno(s). To permanently stop dynos, scale down the process."

To scale down the dynos to 0 through the Platform API, you'll need to use [formation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#formation) API.

Formation List:

```
GET /apps/{app_id_or_name}/formation

$ curl -n https://api.heroku.com/apps/$APP_ID_OR_NAME/formation \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3"
```

Formation Update:

```
PATCH /apps/{app_id_or_name}/formation/{formation_id_or_type}

$ curl -n -X PATCH https://api.heroku.com/apps/$APP_ID_OR_NAME/formation/$FORMATION_ID_OR_TYPE \
  -d '{
  "quantity": 1,
  "size": "standard-1X"
}' \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3"
```

Sending **quantity = 0**  as a parameter will scale the dyno process to zero.