# How to stop a Heroku dyno using the Heroku API so it doesn't restart

Tags: python, heroku, heroku-api

How can a fully stop a Heroku dyno using the Heroku API so it doesn't restart?

I have Heroku set up to run a Python script that always loops and never exits to check sensors. This main.py script is run as a Dyno worker via my Procfile. Right now, it always runs as anticipated. It even restarts upon a crash, which is also helpful for this app.

Using the [Heroku API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#app), I would like to be able to completely stop this process. This won't be reoccurring often, just a failsafe kill-switch. I can stop the dyno worker by logging in to Heroku and clicking the edit button in the Resources tab and turn off the worker. But, I would like to turn off the worker via the API.

I have tried the following API calls (via Postman), which both stop the current process, but after a few seconds, Heroku starts the worker back up again.

**Stop the current Dyno**

```
POST https://api.heroku.com/apps/<app_id>/dynos/worker.1/actions/stop
```

**Deletes / restarts all dynos in the app**

```
DELETE https://api.heroku.com/apps/<app_id>/dynos
```

Also, I can put the app in to maintenance mode, but that only stops HTTP traffic, not the Dynos

```
PATCH https://api.heroku.com/apps/<app_id>
with payload of {"maintenance":true}
```

One option is completely deleting the app, but that's a bit too much for me as it will also remove all log files, and be a pain to set it back up again.

```
DELETE https://api.heroku.com/apps/<app_id>
```

Is there any way to completely stop a Dyno or app via the API until I manually start it back up again?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Heroku [Formation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#formation) API to scale the processes up and down, it will not restart the App by itself.

For detailed answer check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63806415/how-to-add-and-remove-heroku-dynos-through-platform-api).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are stoping the worker rather than a dyno. You have to provide a dyno id.

[Stoping dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#dyno-stop)

After stopping correctly restart to start it again.

[restarting the dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#dyno-restart)

Comment: You do not have to provide a dyno ID. You can also use the dyno name as shown in the docs: dyno_id_or_name. I've tried with both with no difference. In both cases the dyno restarts after stopping.